# How to compare date in format "dd/mm" with DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Please advise how I can check that current date (`DateTime.Now`) is in diapason of dates in format "`dd/mm`". For example - `01.01 <= DateTime.Now <= 01.03` - Current date more that `1st of January` but less that `1st of March`

Comment: You will have to convert both to Date and check.

Comment: So if DateTime.Now is 1st March 23:59  are you expecting your range to evaluate to true ?  If yes then the answers below are incorrect.

Comment: [Diapason](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diapason)?

Comment: Also, consider if today is December 31st, tomorrow is January 1st, which would fail your check.  In other words, you cannot do this without either specifying a year, or asserting that all values are in the same year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `dateStrFrom` be the first input ie, the From Date and `dateStrTo` be the second input ie, the To date. Then you can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to convert it into the required DateTime Object for processing your comparison.

I hope that you are looking for something like this :

```
string dateStrFrom = "01.01"; 
string dateStrTo = "01.03";
DateTime dateFrom, dateTo;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStrFrom, "dd.MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateFrom);
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStrTo, "dd.MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTo);
if (dateFrom <= DateTime.Now && dateTo <= DateTime.Now)
{ 
    // code here this will be the true condition for you
}
```

Comment: Probably not the result he's expecting, this won't match anything after midnight on the 28th of Feb

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, DateTime.ParseExact("01.03", "dd.MM", null))
```

This returns a signed number indicating the relative values of t1 and t2.Value Type Condition Less than zero t1 is earlier than t2. Zero t1 is the same as t2. Greater than zero t1 is later than t2.

Answer (score 1):

```
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("01/01", "dd/MM",null);
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("28/11", "dd/MM", null);

        if (dt1 <= DateTime.Now && DateTime.Now < dt2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
        }
```

if someone find the solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can parse using DateTime.Parse(). For your case you can using the DateTime.Compare()

Sample code will help you.

```
// If you want to compare only date part of DateTime, not time part:
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse("10/11/2016");
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2016");

if (d1.Date > d2.Date)
{
   // do the stuff
}
// For Converting it to String
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");


// Comparison
int result = DateTime.Compare(today, otherdate);
if(result < 0)
MessageBox.Show("Today is earlier than the 'otherdate'");
elseif(result > 0)
MessageBox.Show("Today is later than the 'other date'");
else
MessageBox.Show("Dates are equal...");

// Will give you a DateTime typed object
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2016");
```